# convert textarea value to html content using p tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

need to convert a textarea value to html content with `p` tags instead of new lines
this is my way  - it works - but maybe there is a more native way or a predefined function to do the same

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
let a = $('#tx').val();
let html = '<p>' + a.trim().replace('\n', '</p>\n<p>') + '</p>';
console.log(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='tx'>
lorem
ipsum
</textarea>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can split by newline and get an array. You can map that with template interpolation to wrap tags around. Utilizing the regex `/\n+/` will ignore multiple succeeding newlines.

```
const text = "Hello\nWorld!\n\nHello\nmy\nfriend";
const html = text.split(/\n+/).map(e => `<p>${e}</p>\n`);
```

And a `console.log(html);` looks like this:

```
(5) ["<p>Hello</p>↵", "<p>World!</p>↵", "<p>Hello</p>↵", "<p>my</p>↵", "<p>friend</p>↵"]
```